# Multivariate Regression Error “AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'”

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a multivariate linear regression but I'm getting an error when trying to get the coefficients of the regression model.

The error I'm getting is this: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import seaborn as seabornInstance 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
%matplotlib inline

# Main files
dataset = pd.read_csv('namaste_econ_model.csv')
dataset.shape
dataset.describe()
dataset.isnull().any()

#Dividing data into "attributes" and "labels". X variable contains all the attributes and y variable contains labels.

X = dataset[['Read?', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6' , 'x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16','x17','x18','x19','x20','x21','x22','x23','x24','x25','x26','x27','x28','x29','x30','x31','x32','x33','x34','x35','x36','x37','x38','x39','x40','x41','x42','x43','x44','x45','x46','x47']].values
y = dataset['Change in Profit (BP)'].values
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.tight_layout()
seabornInstance.distplot(dataset['Change in Profit (BP)'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])  
coeff_df
```

Full error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 14, in coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.values` on a pandas dataframe gives you a numpy array. This will not contain column names and such. You do this when setting `X` like this:

```
X = dataset[['Read?', 'x1', .. ,'x47']].values
```

But then you try to get the column names from `X` (which it does not have) by writing `X.columns` here:

```
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
```

So store your column names in a variable or input them again, like this:

```
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, ['Read?', 'x1', .. ,'x47'], columns=['Coefficient'])
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you so much for the support. You're right... that was totally the issue. Now I do have another question, sorry if I'm being opportunistic here... so the x1,x2, etc... are actually dummy variables (ref. https://prnt.sc/payj7q) that came from a categorical variable. So now my output for the coefficients, looks like this...  https://prnt.sc/payio0 I'm doing something wrong here or where should I look to improve the model?  Again, thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

hi remove **values** method

```
X = dataset[['Read?', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6' , 'x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16','x17','x18','x19','x20','x21','x22','x23','x24','x25','x26','x27','x28','x29','x30','x31','x32','x33','x34','x35','x36','x37','x38','x39','x40','x41','x42','x43','x44','x45','x46','x47']]

coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
```